# Как рассчитать количество строк и столбцов в UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit

В `UICollectionView` насколько мне известно нельзя в явном виде указать количество строк и столбцов. Эти параметры рассчитываются автоматически. Одна как разработчику можно получить эти значения? Рассчитать их самостоятельно (через размер ячейки и расстояние между ячейками)? Или есть какое-то свойство, в котором хранится такое значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В UICollectionView нет свойства, которое хранило бы количество строк и столбцов. Ячейки устанавливаются одна за другой слева направо, пока есть место, а когда место заканчивается, новая ячейка переносится на новую строку.

Зная количество ячеек, их размеры, расстояние между ними, а также ширину/высоту экрана (или superview), можно рассчитать количество строк и столбцов.

Также, в зависимости от задачи, можно пойти от обратного: зная ширину/высоту экрана, определить размеры ячейки. Таким образом, можно разместить на экране нужное количество строк и столбцов.

**UPDATE**

Как вариант:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CollectionViewController1: UICollectionViewController {

    let numberOfItems = 10

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let layout = self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let width = Float(self.collectionView!.frame.width)
        let itemWidth = Float(layout.itemSize.width)
        let itemSpacing = Float(layout.minimumInteritemSpacing)
        let totalWidth = (itemWidth + itemSpacing) * Float(numberOfItems)

        let rowCount = lroundf(totalWidth / width)
        let colCount = Int(width / (itemWidth + itemSpacing))
        print("Количество строк: \(rowCount)")
        print("Количество столбцов: \(colCount)")
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.numberOfItems
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue

        return cell
    }

}
```

[image: img]
[image: img]

Comment: Спасибо. Но я бы хотел в виде кода это. Может библиотека какая-нибудь есть?

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.